# How to merge multiple $group into $project in aggregate mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using aggregate to query data in MongoDB but I have an issue with $group, I want to merge multiple $group stage to one $project at final but look like it doesn't seem to works as my expected. In the code below when I am excute it I don't get any results except `_id`. How can I resolve this issue?

Here is my aggregate pipelines:

```
const user = userCollection.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
         _id: ObjectId(id)
      }
    },

    // lookup images list
    {
       $lookup: {...}
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: '$images',
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
        },
    },
    { $sort: { 'images.createdAt': -1 } },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$_id',            
            images: {
                $push: '$images',
            },
        },
    },

    // lookup blocked list
    {
       $lookup: {...}
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: '$blocked',
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
        },
    },
    { $sort: { 'blocked.createdAt': -1 } },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$_id',            
            blocked: {
                $push: '$blocked',
            },
        },
    },

    // lookup followers list
    {
       $lookup: {...}
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: '$followers',
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
        },
    },
    { $sort: { 'followers.createdAt': -1 } },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$_id',            
            followers: {
                $push: '$followers',
            },
        },
    },


    {
       $project: {
          _id: 1,
          name: 1,
          age: 1,
          bio: 1,
          images: 1,
          blocked: 1,
          followers: 1,
       }
    }

]);

console.log(user);
// Results: [{ _id: '...' }, { _id: '...' }, { _id: '...' }, { _id: '...' }]
```

Comment: Hold on a moment. Why are you `$unwind`ing just to immediately `$group` the same documents back together by their `_id` values? Can you avoid doing that altogether? It's not clear it's changing the output in any way apart from dropping the fields that you're trying to get back. I think if you simplify the pipeline to just `$match`, the 3 `$lookup`s, and the trailing `$project` then you will get your desired output

Comment: @user20042973  , I use `$group` to group by _id of the same documents because I need use `$unwind` to sort `images` & `blocked` fields by timestamps or count duplicates in these arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, it at least clarifies things a little bit. But I think we can achieve your desired results in a better way. What version of MongoDB are you running on? (The direct answer to your question would be to keep capture the source doc via `$$ROOT` in each of the `$group` stages, but we should try to avoid that if we can)

Comment: @user20042973  I am using the latest version of MongoDB .  maybe I'll solve this via `$$ROOT`. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user20042973 Can you create an answer for my question? I would love to accept for your answer 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general guideline to keep in mind is that the the following sequence to process arrays is an anti-pattern:

1. `$unwind`
2. Processing the unwound array, eg filtering it with `$match` or `$sort`ing it
3. `$group`ing the data back together using `_id: '$_id'

Anytime you see that you should try to look around for other operators that can process the arrays inline without having to deconstruct and then reconstruct the documents.

In your situation, I'd look to do something similar to the following:

```
[
  { $match: { ... } },
  { $lookup: { ... as: 'images' } },
  { $lookup: { ... as: 'blocked' } },
  { $lookup: { ... as: 'followers' } },
  {
     $project: {
      _id: 1,
      name: 1,
      age: 1,
      bio: 1,
      images: {
        $sortArray: { input: "$images", sortBy: { createdAt: -1 } }
      },
      blocked: {
        $sortArray: { input: "$blocked", sortBy: { createdAt: -1 } }
      },
      followers: {
        $sortArray: { input: "$followers", sortBy: { createdAt: -1 } }
      },
     }
  }
]
```

Specifically we are using [the `$sortArray` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sortArray/) in the final `$project` stage to do the array processing that was mentioned.

A simple demonstration of `$sortArray` can be found in [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zwUQsyHxnxM).

Alternatively, either if on a version prior to that operator becoming available or if additional logic is required, you could consider using [this `$lookup` syntax](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#correlated-subqueries-using-concise-syntax):

```
[
  ...
  { $lookup: 
    {
      from: 'images',
      localField: 'imageField',
      foreignField: 'imageField',
      pipeline: [
        { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } }
      ]
      as: 'images'
    } 
  },
  ...
]
```